# How can I take a list of file names in python and assign each file name as a number for later use?

Tags: python, windows, string, list

Here is what I have so far in Windows:

```
    import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/any/Desktop/test")
for files in os.listdir("."):

    print files
```

Now it prints this:

```
test picture.jpg
test script.bat
test text.txt
```

But now where I am stuck is the output is going to be random with each folder done so my idea of a solution is to have it take the list and label each one individually as

```
filename1 
filename2
filename3
```

So now `filename1 = test picture.jpg`

*Edit*

Well what I am trying to do is later in my code each filename will be used for example say I was trying to rename my files so that any of those files that contained the letter 'e' in it, it would be changed to an 'a' character:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/any/Desktop/test")
for files in os.listdir("."):

    print files



files = files.replace('e', 'a')
print files
```

But I need to be able to have it do each filename individually so the code could look something like this:

```
import os
    os.chdir("C:/Users/any/Desktop/test")
    for files in os.listdir("."):

        print filename1



    filename1 = filename1.replace('e', 'a')
    print filename1
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a list, which you already have. What's it going to be used for?

Comment: Just replace `for files in os.listdir("."):` with `for filename in os.listdir("."):`, and then replace `print filename1` line with `print filename.replace("e", "a")`. Involving things like `filename1` etc doesn't make sense in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I am not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do, you could just try this:

```
dirlist = os.listdir('.')
```

then each index, starting with zero, of `dirlist` would yield an entry from your directory. The index values would in effect take the place of the numbers for your filenames.

So rather than having

```
filename1 
filename2
filename3
```

you'd have

```
dirlist[0]
dirlist[1]
dirlist[2]
```

with minimal effort, and could easily refer to individual entries in any order with the index.

*And* as an added bonus, you could easily iterate through this list of names with a `for`-loop if need be

```
for names in dirlist:
   ...
```

which would be a bit more tricky with the individual filenames you mentioned in your original post.

**Update**:

Given your edit to your post, you would have been able to achieve your goal with pretty much your original code:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/any/Desktop/test")
for fname in os.listdir("."):
    fname = fname.replace('e', 'a')
    print fname
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add all those names into a list, you'll have a pre-built index and numbering system:

```
>>> lst = ['a','b','c']
>>> lst.index('b')
1
>>> lst[1]
'b'
```

In your case:

```
files = os.listdir('.')
files[0] # first file
files[3] # fourth file (first one is 0)
```

Comment: Why do you need `[f for f in os.listdir('.')]` instead of just `os.listdir('.')`?

Comment: Eh, good point. Need morning coffee first before SO question answer time. Thanks @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to name them **incrementally** like that why not just store them in a **list**?

```
filenames = []
filenames.extend(os.listdir("."))

filenames[0] # filename1 equivalent
filenames[1] # filename2 equivalent
```

The reason I've used `extend` here is it sounds like you want to construct a list of file names from *various* folders.

Comment: That would be a list with a single list in it (and would have to be accessed like `filenames[0][0], filenames[0][1]`, not the way you have). Why not just `filenames  = os.listdir(".")`

Comment: I interpreted the question as wanting to get a list of filenames from _various_ folders ("**random with each folder**", as OP quoted). I may have misinterpreted the intention. But yes @DavidRobinson, I did not intend to use `append`.